# Почему связывание аргументов запроса нарушает сам запрос?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Пишу на php 5.6 запрос к базе данных используя PDO. СУБД MySQL.

**Нерабочий** вариант:

```
       /**
        * Returns value from db using simple query.
        *
        * @param  object  $dbConnection
        * @param  string  $table
        * @param  string  $column
        * @param  string  $value
        * @return mixed
        */
        private function getValue($dbConnection, $table, $column, $value) {
            $query = 'SELECT :column FROM `:table` WHERE :column = ":value"';

            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($query);

            $stmt->bindParam(':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':column', $column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();

            $record = $stmt->fetch(/*PDO::FETCH_ASSOC*/);

            return $record[$column];
    }
```

Пробовала и этот варианта связывания: `$stmt->execute(['table' => $table, 'column' => $column, 'value' => $value]);`.

**Рабочий** вариант:

```
private function getValue($dbConnection, $table, $column, $value) {
            $query = 'SELECT '.$column.' FROM `'.$table.'` WHERE '.$column.' = "'.$value.'"';

            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            $record = $stmt->fetch(/*PDO::FETCH_ASSOC*/);

            return $record[$column];
        }
```

Как видите, реализации данной функции отличаются тем, что в пока нерабочей версии аргументы запроса связываются с запросом посредством инструмента связывания PDO (грамотный, более безопасный и читаемый подход). Во второй реализации связывание происходит посредством конкатенации. Видимо, что-то в механизме связывания PDO искажает запрос, ведь первая реализация функции возвращает null при тех же аргментах. `die($dbConnection->errorInfo());` перед `return` возвращает просто `Array`. Итак, почему связывание аргументов запроса нарушает сам запрос?

Comment: имена таблиц и полей вообще не могут быть параметрами в принципе. Этот функционал предназначен, чтобы сервер подготовил план запроса, и потом многоразово подставлять туда параметры. Очевидно, что ни о какой подготовке плана и даже проверки синтаксиса и речи быть не  может, когда вы параметров хотите объявить имя таблицы или поля. Параметры используются исключительно для значений полей.

Comment: @teran почему тогда вот такое построение запроса `$query = 'SELECT '.$column.' FROM \`'.$table.'\` WHERE '.$column.' = ":value"'` тоже не даёт результатов?

Comment: смотрите ошибки выполнения. Особого смысла в таком запросе правда нет. вам вернется либо пустой набор, либо набор из `$value`, так что если вы хотите проверить наличие таких значений в таблице, то верните `count()` (либо сделайте `limit 1`), он вернет просто количество, а не набор одинаковых строк.

Comment: @teran такие значения в таблице явно есть. Я тестирую этот скрипт с помощью отправки одного и того же запроса, изменяя только реализацию функции. При конкатенации скрипт возващает то, что мне нужно. При binding (даже вот как в последнем примере, делаю bind только одного параметра) ничего не возвращается.

Comment: вот и добавьте тогда код этого третьего варианта. добавьте в него вывод ошибок, и если ошибка будет, то ее текст.

Comment: и кавычки вокруг `":value"` уберите, они там не нужны, более того как раз и приведут к ошибке.

Comment: @teran убрала кавычки - заработало. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @teran кстати, по поводу имён таблиц и полей в качестве параметров запроса. У меня есть вот такая протестированная функция https://pastebin.com/BsMmjpsP

Comment: @teran на основе этой функции я и писал getValue. Видимо, здесь на всё влияет перечисление выборки.

Comment: вероятно это будет работать в режиме эмуляции.

Comment: @J.Huxley, проверил Вашу "протестированную" функцию из пастбина - не работает она. В каком месте она протестирована?  на чем вообще? Причем она не просто не работает - она и не должна ни при каких обстоятельствах работать, т.к. нарушает логику использования связывания переменных. Связывать можно только значения - никаких связываний названий полей/таблиц/ключевых_слов/т.д. нет и быть не может (teran писал об этом ещё в первом комменте и объяснил почему)